# Force selenium to use the portable firefox application

Tags: selenium, python, robotframework

I have installed firefox 14 and has firefox **portable** version 25.0.1 on the machine, where I run tests for a web site.

Due to a limitation in the site I'm testing, I cannot run my tests on firefox 14 installation. Also I cannot upgrade the firefox 14 installation.

So I'm looking into a solution where I can use this portable firefox version instead of the installed firefox 14 version.

How should I force selenium to use this portable version and not the installed version?If someone could direct me to some descriptive article/blog that would be great.

PS: python is the used language

Comment: This question is so old that it is no longer relevant.  Since Firefox implemented auto-upgrading, everyone is generally on the latest version.  I would argue that older versions of Firefox should not be suppported.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate Selenium set the full path to the Firefox install you want to use instead of just using "firefox" which will use the defaul path.

```
  def setUp(self):
       self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla
       self.selenium.start()
```

Comment: thanks. I'm using robot frame work and used the browser name as: firefox D:\\Firefox Portable\\FirefoxPortable\\firefox.exe

But the problem is it is giving a 'value error' which says 'firefox D:\Firefox Portable\FirefoxPortable\firefox.exe is not a supported browser.'

Answer (score 0):

For Java:

```java
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/oracle/firefox-10.0/firefox"));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
```

Comment: The question is about Python and Robot Framework.